# Nested routing react-router-dom v6 not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to React and I am following [this](https://github.com/ZhangMYihua/lesson-23) project. But I am stuck on converting the nested routed in version6 of react-router-dom.

In V5 it is as follows:

App.js

```
  return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
          <Route path='/shop' component={ShopPage} />
          <Route exact path='/checkout' component={CheckoutPage} />
          <Route
            exact
            path='/signin'
            render={() =>
              this.props.currentUser ? (
                <Redirect to='/' />
              ) : (
                <SignInAndSignUpPage />
              )
            }
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
```

ShopPage

```
      const ShopPage = ({ match }) => (
  <div className='shop-page'>
    <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionsOverview} />
    <Route path={`${match.path}/:collectionId`} component={CollectionPage} />
  </div>
);
```

I want to convert it in V6 and I had tried as follows:

My App.js

```
return (
  <div >
    <Header />
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path='/shop' element={<ShopPage />} />
        
      <Route path='/checkout' element={<CheckoutPage />} />
      <Route path='/signin' element={<>
        {this.props.currentUser ?
          <Navigate to="/" />
          :
          <SignInAndSignUpPage />

        }
      </>
      }

      />

      <Route path='/signin' element={this.props.user ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <SignInAndSignUpPage />} />
     

    </Routes>
  </div>
);
```

My Shopage

```
    const ShopPage = () => {
    let { pathname } = useLocation();

    console.log(pathname);
   
    return (
        <div className='shop-page'>
            <Routes>
                <Route path={`${pathname}`} element={<CollectionsOverview />} />
                <Route path={`${pathname}/:collectionId`} element={<CollectionItems />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    )
};
```

In pathname console log I am getting `/shop` but the items are not showing.
How can acheive nested routing in v6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `CollectionsOverview` is what is rendered exactly on `"/shop"`. Nested routes operate a little different in v6 than they did in v5. You don't need to get the current path/url to build nested routes/links, you can just use relative routes.

Example:

```
const ShopPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className='shop-page'>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<CollectionsOverview />} />
        <Route path=":collectionId" element={<CollectionItems />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Optionally, you can can convert `ShopPage` into a layout route.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ShopPage = () => (
  <div className='shop-page'>
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);
```

App

```
return (
  <div >
    <Header />
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path='/shop' element={<ShopPage />}>
        <Route index element={<CollectionsOverview />} />
        <Route path=":collectionId" element={<CollectionItems />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/checkout' element={<CheckoutPage />} />
      <Route
        path='/signin'
        element={this.props.currentUser
          ? <Navigate to="/" />
          : <SignInAndSignUpPage />
        }
      />
      <Route
        path='/signin'
        element={this.props.user
          ? <Navigate to="/" />
          : <SignInAndSignUpPage />
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  </div>
);
```